# update field based on another field in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I use `mongoengine` (which is ORM wrapper around `pymongo`).
`url` field in the document contains a relative path (like `/abc/blog/12/01`) and I want to bulk update a `fullUrl` field so it would look like `https://mywebsite.com/abc/blog/12/01`
In Django ORM it's easy to do with `update(newfield=F('oldfield')`. Is there a way to do the same in `mongoengine`?

```
class ArticleLink(Document):
    url = StringField()
    fullUrl=URLField()
```

So I suspect something like that **won't** work:

```
ArticleLink.objects.update(fullUrl=Q('url'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry that was much more straightforward than I thought:

```py
HEAD = 'https://example.com'
pipeline = [
    {"$set": {"fullUrl": {"$concat": [HEAD, "$url"]}}}
]
data = ArticleLink.objects().aggregate(*pipeline)
```